# Rails/Postgres brittle test environment not creating correct datatypes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using the `citext` extension because of Postgres's shortcoming with respect to not having a global feature to allow case-insensitive searching.

However, in my Rails 3.2 application when I run:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

my objects are created with `text` datatypes, instead of `citext`. How can I force the above rake command to create the database and add the extensions that my application requires in order to do the kind of searching that should just be baked in already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the citext extension to your test database. Unfortunately, in the standard implementation of db:test:prepare the database is dropped and recreated, so the extension is gone.

I found myself in the same situation and had to resort to override db:test:purge (which is called prior to prepare) with my own implementation so instead of dropping the database it would just drop the objects (a solution based on 'DROP OWNED BY username').

UPDATE with rake task code:
So my rake task looks like this. I put it on lib/tasks/overrides/database.rake; but that's up to you.

```
 namespace :db do  
   namespace :test do
     task :purge => []
     Rake::Task["purge"].clear

     # desc overrides default task to drop all objects in database instead of the db itself (only postgresql)
     task :purge => [:environment, :load_config] do
       abcs = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations
       case abcs['test']['adapter']
         when /postgresql/
           # original implementation commented out
           #ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
           #drop_database(abcs['test'])
           #create_database(abcs['test'])
           drop_database_objects(abcs['test'])
       end
     end
   end
 end

 def drop_database_objects(config)
   case config['adapter']
   when /postgresql/
     ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
     sql = "DROP OWNED BY #{config['username']}"
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute sql 
   end 
 end
```

I am omitting the parts that haven't changed, but you can see the original at [database.rake](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake).
A note: I found that Postgresql 9.2.2 has a problem with the DROP OWNED BY, you'll be fine using 9.2.1 and 9.2.3; it's just that one version.

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be willing to share that. I'll put a bounty on this.

Comment: Thanks boulder. I can't put a bounty on until the question is 2 days old. I'll hook you up then. In the meantime I looped through all AR models, trapped all of the attribute names with "character varying" and converted the columns with the ALTER TABLE command. But I need your solution for another reason: all of my supporting, read-only schemas are dropped every time db:test:prepare is run.

Comment: There you go; no need to wait for 2 days. Happy to help.